# Google Enterprise Support Center API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can't find any documentation anywhere regarding whether or not Google has an API for the enterprise google support center that allows me to retrieve cases associated with my account. Does anyone know if this is possible, or am I stuck using the [support center](https://enterprise.google.com/supportcenter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Google Cloud Platform Support representative and at the moment there is no API available to manage Google Cloud Support cases. Actually it's a good idea so we've filed a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/68797857) for that.

You can star the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/68797857) to get email notifications and track its progress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is great to hear. I am currently tracking this feature request. I will keep my fingers crossed that it is added soon!